# How can I make a cmd line utility run in a Async BackgroundWorker process in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How can I make a cmd line utility run in a Async BackgroundWorker process in vb.net?

Example:

```
Private Sub UpgradeButton_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpgradeButton.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim MyWorkingDirectory = "C:\Windows\System32\"
    Dim MyFileName As String = "notepad.exe"
    Dim MyArguments As String = ""

    Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = MyWorkingDirectory
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = MyFileName
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = MyArguments
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    myProcess.Start()
    ' Wait until it ends.
    myProcess.WaitForExit()
    ' Close the process to free resources.
    myProcess.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code is not working - I suppose it doesn't work - and I'd like to suggest you something else: use a Thread instead of BackgroundWorker. if you need only to start the application, use a simple thread:

```
Public Shared Sub ThreadProc()
    ''Starth the process here!
End Sub


Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf ThreadProc)
t.IsBackground = True
t.Start()
```

And the started thread opens the process you need and the main thread continues its execution. I hope this is the answer you need!